# Salvar atributo de formulário sem o name definido

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, post

Estou com um problema em um script php. O atributo name de uma página recebe um valor que é gerado por um array. O que eu preciso fazer é basicamente gerar uma tabela em que cada linha tem um botão que serve para deletar a mesma informação recebida do banco de dados, esse botão é o qual utilizo o atributo name para salvar a id do registro recebida. Então, eu não sei oque coloco na outra página php para que esse valor seja salvo. Colocarei o código abaixo para maior analise.

A baixo a pagina php que mostra os elementos na tela.

```
<?php
        $query = sprintf("SELECT conteudo, autor, titulo, pagina, id FROM atualizacoes ORDER BY id DESC");

        $dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

        $linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);

        $total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
        ?>
                <body>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <form name="login" method="post" action="../removendo.php">
                <h2 style="color: white">Atualizando blog</h2>

            <table class="tabelaconteudo">

                        <?php
                        if($total>0){
                            do{

                                ?>
                                <tr>
    `<td><?= $linha['titulo']?></td>
    <td><?= $linha['pagina'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $linha['autor'] ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="btn-cad" style="color: white" value="Apagar"
name="ref_<?= $linha['id'] ?>"></td> //AQUI É O CAMPO O QUAL NÃO CONSIGO SALVAR A INFORMAÇÃO
    </tr>


                            <?php

                            }while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));

                        }
                        ?>

            </table>
                    </form>

            </div>
            </div>
            </body>
```

Abaixo a página php que é carregada quando pressionado o botão submit (o mesmo que não consigo definir um name especifico).

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
    $id=$_POST['NAME QUE NAO ESTA DEFINIDO'];
    $restid = substr($id, 1, 4);
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM atualizacoes WHERE id = $restid");
    echo"
<script>
document.getElementById('loader').onpageshow = alertfunc();
function alertfunc() {
    alert('Ocorreu algum erro.'$sql);
    }
</script>

";
?>
```

Comecei com programação web a pouco tempo, e tudo que aprendi com php até agora foi isso. Já varri a internet inteira atras disso e nunca achei algo concreto até agora, ai então no desespero venho até aqui por ajuda. Desde já agradeço á todos que dispuseram-se a ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>
  <form name="login" method="post" action="../removendo.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="Apagar" value="ref_<?= $linha['id'] ?>" name="campo_para_apagar" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn-cad" value="Apagar" name="submit" />
  </form>
</td>
```

Se você só envia esses valores de cada vez, uma solução é abrir um `<form>` diferente para cada linha da tabela, com um input escondido que tem o seu valor. Assim quando você clicar em Apagar ele vai mandar somente o valor daquele input e ele vai estar disponível no request como

```
$id = $_POST['campo_para_apagar'];
```

Comment: Muito obrigado testei sua solução e consegui resolver meu problema!! Muitíssimo Obrigado!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um array no atributo name assim:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-cad" style="color: white" value="Apagar"
name="ref[<?= $linha['id'] ?>]">
```

e no PHP obter o ID assim:

```
$id = key($_POST['ref']);
```